# getchar() only calling every other time

Tags: c, getchar

While using Ch Standard Interpreter, `getchar()` only runs every other line.

```
C:/> char a = getchar();
C:/> char b = getchar();
b
C:/> char c = getchar();
C:/> char d = getchar();
d
```

I have the same issue when using `scanf("%c", &a)` instead; in Vim the statement is skipped.

```
printf("\nType of Something\nA for SomethingA\nB for SomethingB "
        "\nC for SomethingC\n\nSelect (A,B,C) > ");
char letter = getchar(); // This statement gets skipped
return 0;
```

Comment: This is apparently an oddity of `Ch`; it's definitely not a property of the C language.

Comment: After compiling with GCC it just does not work at all.

Comment: Idea maybe add a getchar(); between a & b/c & d. because it looks to me like the one is getting the others input.

Comment: That just returns the ASCII int value of the char. i.e `getchar();`, scan in "a" returns 97. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type "A" on the keyboard, you first press "A", and then you press "ENTER", right? So `getchar()` or `scanf("%c", ....)` gets two characters to read: "A", and the newline character from the "ENTER" key.

If you use your code in a loop, or just repeatedly, the first getchar() will read the newline character from the previous input.

Comment: I see, I have two previous `scanf("%d")` statements in my code, `getchar()` works when I comment them out; does that mean I need to clear the input buffer or something?

Comment: @Christopher: Yes, after scanf("%d") there is a newline left in the buffer. Just read it with gethcar(). Or better: use a loop, calling getchar() until it finds that newline.

Comment: That seems really sloppy, is there a way to prevent `\n` or is this the only way?

Comment: Well, getchar() is supposed to read each character in the input stream, and that is what it does. But in cases like this it is usually recommended to read each line with fgets(), and then analyze that line in a separate step.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense now. :)